# How to capture keyboard inputs like Windows explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-events

I have custom dropdown select and capturing `keydown` event which triggers an event for each input pressed on keyboard.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  console.log('keydown event\n\n' + 'key: ' + keyName);
});
```

[image]

Pressing "t" and "w" triggers event two successive events. But I need to capture "tw" as my search term then highlight it in dropdown.
(Or)
Just I need to capture all keys pressed continuously.

I am looking for something in Windows explorer where quickly pressing "d" & "e" highlights "Dev Tools".

[image]

How to capture these in JavaScript with proper timeout or something?

Comment: How are you going to use JS in Win Explorer?  Have you been able to make it select with just one key?

Comment: Where do you intend to do this? Can you post some HTML markup to show that?

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
let pressed = [];
let timeoutId;

document.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
  pressed.push(e.key);

  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }

  timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(pressed.join(''));
    pressed = [];
  }, 400); //300-400ms timeout is optimal
});
```

Comment: 400ms looks optimal for the timeout.